# Can't add object to static NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, static, delegates, nsmutablearray

I have a static variable on appDelegate declared like this:

appdelegate.h file:

```
+(NSMutableArray*)allBanco;
+(void)setAllBanco:(NSMutableArray*)value;
```

appdelegate.m file:

```
static NSMutableArray * allBanco;

+(NSMutableArray*)allBanco
{
    return allBanco;
}

+(void)setAllBanco:(NSMutableArray*)value
{
    if(allBanco != value)
    {
        [allBanco release];
        allBanco = [value copy];
    }
}
```

I tried to acess it on other class 
on .m file:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

    [[AppDelegate allBanco] addObject:testeObj];
```

i cant understand why,i can log the

```
NSLog(@"%i",[[AppDelegate allBanco] count]);
```

and goes ok.

I tried :

```
    NSMutableArray * temp = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
    temp = [AppDelegate allBanco];
    [temp addObject:testeObj];
    [AppDelegate setAllBanco:temp];
```

and doest work.

Comment: What is the error / error message?

Comment: I dont know if its correct, but the point is exactly when i try to add,or temp = [AppDelegate allBanco];  and the error message is 

-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6107f80
2011-11-16 21:30:06.674 Prototipo[4992:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6107f80'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you created your array properly, keep in mind that `-copy` returns an *immutable* copy, so you may crash later when modifying it.

---

Now that you added your error, I'm quite sure this is indeed the problem:

> `-[__NSArrayI addObject:]`: unrecognized selector sent to instance

You tried to add an object in a NSArray, not a NSMutableArray. Try using `-mutableCopy`.

Comment: +1, Good catch - I think this is more likely the OP's problem than I what I was guessing.

Comment: I dont get it now,in the declaration is exactly an NSMutableArray,the copy is changing the proprierty?

Comment: @ViniciusAlbino It won't change it, but copy is a method which returns an immutable version of you object. So you end up with a NSMutableArray pointer pointing to a NSArray. PS: There should be a warning in this line.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't created an object for `allBanco` to point to.  Change your method so that you can create one if it doesn't exist yet:

```
+(NSMutableArray*)allBanco
{
    if (!allBanco)
       allBanco = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return allBanco;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Norum, I though this could be the problem initially but then spot the `copy`.